# Conditional component

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion

Is there a way to

1. get a particular pipeline's, say P1, status (failed / completed) in conditional component in pipeline P2?
2. Can we call a pipeline from conditional component?

Usecase:
I have functional pipelines F1, F2, F3 etc and audit pipelines as audit_success and audit_failure. If I can get F3's status in 1 single audit pipeline, I can have 2 branches in same pipeline thereby avoiding creation of 2 pipelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no conditional component that checks for another pipeline's status. However, you can achieve this through pipeline triggers, but as you mentioned it does require two different pipelines.

Comment: Thanks Edwin. Is there a way to set/create namespace variable or its value from within a pipeline by firing API call, may be through post action plugin? If yes, in my single audit pipeline, I can then fetch the value of that variable and decide further course?

Comment: that's a good idea to test. I have not try it myself, but you can potentially do that. There is an HTTP postaction plugin, and you can set the preference of the downstream pipeline through API (https://cdap.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DOCS/pages/477561058/Preferences+Microservices)